# sql in ms-access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table name  customers with two columns,  case id and owner. I need to write a query to select random 5 caseids for every name in owner column.please help

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: When you clicked to create this post the button said "Ask Question". But "I want" or "I need" is not a question. We will help you fix bugs. Generally most people here will not just do your work for you completely, unless it's trivial. What research have you done? What code have you tried? What problem are you facing? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further guidance on how to ask a useful question.

Answer (score 2):

For a start, you need something like:

```
SELECT TOP 5
    ID, 
    [Case ID], 
    [Owner], 
    Rnd(-Timer()*[ID]) AS RandomRecord
FROM 
    [Cases]
ORDER BY 
    Rnd(-Timer()*[ID]);
```

to be used as a subquery filtered on OwnerID of your Owners' table.

I once posted an article on this with a lot more details:

[Random Rows in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33030/Random-Rows-in-Microsoft-Access.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id in (select top 5 id
               from t as t2
               where t2.name = t.name
               order by Rnd(-Timer()*[ID])
              );
```

Comment: Thanks. Not the downvoter, sorry for my direct way of expressing myself.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth . . . No problem at all.  You were no doubt correct.   It bothers me that Microsoft in general doesn't seem to understand volatile functions and query optimization.

Comment: Hello when i use this code it gives me a input field and ask for someinput first as t2 name and then as t1 name, can youexplain more into it

Comment: @chiragpuri . . . There is no `t1.name` in this query.  `t` is for your table name.